# Find value and key in multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [word] => 1 
        [question] => php 
        [position] => 11 
    )
    [1] => Array ( 
        [word] => sql 
        [question] => 1 
        [position] => 22 
    ) 
)
```

I need to find if [position] => 22 exists in my array and retain the array path for further reference. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? There are a lot of posts on this site that deal with multidimensional arrays, and they should be able to at least get you started if you haven't.

Comment: you need the path or the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
$array = array 
( 
    array ( 
        "word" => 1,
        "question" => php,
        "position" => 11 
    ),
    array ( 
        "word" => sql,
        "question" => 1,
        "position" => 22 
    ) 
);

foreach($array as $item)
{
    foreach($item as $key=>$value)
    {
        if($key=="position" && $value=="22")
        {
           echo "found";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it doesn't work if he had an array with 3 level of depth

Comment: Sorry, he changed the question while I was writing

Comment: this solution has an inneceary loop searching for 'position'. and as all responses here do not return the "path" (the position on the main array)

Answer (score 3):

Example of code for the solution "Ancide" provide.

```
$found = false;

foreach ($array as $array_item) {
    if (isset($array_item['position'] && $array_item['position'] == "22")) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: only there's a little mistake in code, should be `if (isset($array_item['position']) && $array_item['position'] == "22")`

Answer (score 0):

First check if they key exists using `isset`, then if the key exists, check that the value is equal to your compare value.

Edit: I missed that there were two arrays. To solve this, iterate through each array and do the check in each cycle. If the check is positive you know which array it is by looking at the current index.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no other solution than to loop through the array an check whether there is a key "position" and value "22"

Answer (score 0):

Try with this function:

```
function findKey($array, $mykey) {
    if(array_key_exists($mykey, $array))
        return true;

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value))
            return findKey($value, $mykey);
    }

    return false;
}

if(findKey($search_array, 'theKey')) {
    echo "The element is in the array";
} else {
    echo "Not in array";
}
```

Comment: Added this if someone need any level of depth.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function exists($array,$fkey,$fval)
{
foreach($array as $items)
{
   foreach($items as $key => $val)
     if($key == $fkey and $val == $fval)return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Example:

`if(exists($your_array,"position",22))echo("found");`

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem:

```
<?php

foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if(isset($v['position']) && $v['position'] == 22) {
    $key = $k;  
    }
}
echo $key;

//$array[$key]['position'] = 22

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function findPath($array, $value) {
    foreach($array as $key => $subArray)  if(subArray['position'] === $value) return $key;
    return false;  // or whatever if not found
}


echo findPath($x, 22);  //  returns 1


$x= Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [word] => 1 
        [question] => php 
        [position] => 11 
    )
    [1] => Array ( 
        [word] => sql 
        [question] => 1 
        [position] => 22 
    ) 
)
```